# How to make a zone where user can tap to do a specify action)?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, touch

How to make a zone where user can tap to do a specify action)? same below picture: 
[image]

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a transparent `UIButton` in that zone.

Comment: Hic, it so easy, I'm feel asshamed! Thank so much!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I think is to put there an instance of UIButton with UIButtonTypeCustom type (that is with no image and transparent background) and set showsTouchWhenHighlighted to NO.